# Git newbie having trouble when cloning new project

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm sure this has been asked before in some context, but after trying a few proposed solutions on different questions I'm not sure if I've been asking the right question in the first place, but here's my situation.

I have project ABC that I've been working on for months cloned under C:/Users/admin/ABC. Everything is working fine, I'm using Git Bash (on Windows) to push & pull, and XAMPP to run Apache and MySQL so I can view changes via localhost. A few days ago I was told to git clone project DEF, which was originally part of ABC but split into a new project. Whenever I clone DEF, it ends up in ABC's directory, and thus does not display appropriately as it should. ABC and DEF need to be on the same level, but I need to be able to access and push/pull from both. How do I make sure it clones into it's own directory and not into ABC?

In addition, how do I make sure my XAMPP settings and localhost work well on the DEF directory once it's separated? How do I switch between projects? I've been trying to reach my teammate but he is out for the week and is unable to help me. Would appreciate any advice, hopefully this is an easy issue that I'm just overthinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your project *ABC* is in `C:/Users/admin/ABC`, and you want to clone project *DEF* so that it shows up in `C:/Users/admin/DEF`, here's how to do that using Git Bash:

```
# cd into C:/Users/admin - adjust if necessary
cd /c/Users/admin

# Clone the DEF repo, assuming this is the URL
git clone https://github.com/project/DEF

# cd into DEF
cd DEF
```

Once you have done that, remove the other *DEF* folder that you accidentally put into the *ABC* folder.

To switch between projects, you can `cd` into each directory. Assuming you are in `ABC`, you can

```
cd ../DEF
```

to go into the `DEF` folder. Use the same trick to move back to `ABC`:

```
cd ../ABC
```

It's hard to say more without knowing your exact project structure.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I wasn't aware of the use for the _cd_ command in Bash (and I guess everything else I tried wasn't the right command for the program), but it'll be very useful. I found a few Q&As on the XAMPP/localhost issues, so I can say this question is resolved. Appreciate the help.